# Complex Analysis need a new book.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need a reference with some worked out very basic proofs of limits using $ \epsilon / \delta $ in $\mathbb {C}$ my book doesnt have any examples.

i have never taken an analysis class but i do have some knowledge of them from calculus ( we often saw them in proofs but never actually had to evaluate one ourselves) If i could see a couple examples im sure i can fumble my way through understanding it. I have asked several of the basic questions in my book that don't have worked out examples on this site.

Sadly they have all just been down-voted multiple times as a bad question, so im hoping someone can point me in the direction of a book/resource that has some basic ones worked out.

I dont need anything fancy for the most part we will simply use theorems to show when we can take a derivative etc but i would really like a basic understanding of whats going on.

Comment: If what you want are basic examples worked out, [Schaum's](https://www.amazon.ca/Schaums-Outline-Complex-Variables-2ed/dp/0071615695) is often a good resource.